# What happens if I quit my job? France on long-stay visa

Tags: visa, working-visas, france, working

I've been searching and haven't been able to find a definitive answer to this question.

I'm currently in France on a long-stay visa which bears the statement "travailleur temporaire." My contract is a CDD from October to April and my visa is valid until mid-May. I was just wondering, if I was to quit my job after December, would I still legally be able to stay in the country until May? I don't plan on getting another job in the 4.5 months that I will remain in France - I simply want to take some French classes and travel around Europe.

I am contracted by a government department so it's a pretty official job. I have had no answer from the consulate back home.

Comment: Note that technically, you may not simply quit a CDD, you can only end it before its term for a limited number of reasons (finding a permanent job, moving to your spouse, etc.) In practice, it's unlikely your employer would sue you for damages but that's the law.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike other countries, France does not have a notion of a visa or residence permit automatically becoming invalid. If you cease to fulfill the requirements, the *préfecture* can however decide to invalidate it. So your visa remains valid until they notify you otherwise. If they do that, they will also in most cases issue an *obligation de quitter le territoire français* and give you 30 days to leave France by your own means. After these 30 days the consequences become more serious (removal, etc.)

As far as I know, the *préfectures* typically don't bother. They wait for the end of the 1-year term and reevaluate people's situation when they need to renew their residence titles. Note that leaving your job without prior authorization can have consequences for the renewal *even if you found another one in the meantime*. It doesn't seem to be the case for you but that's one factor to consider.

Comment: This is what I was under the impression would happen but wanted to double check - I have contacted the French Consulate in Australia but I truly would not be surprised if I didn't receive a response. Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 0):

Since the duration of your issued **travailleur temporaire** was for a specific contract, which you wish to terminate earlier

- you should assume that the issued permit is no longer valid since the conditions have changed

You should go and ask the responsible **Prefecture** if your present permit needs to be adapted.

The second link below, mentions changing an employer but not for simply remaing without working

- that link also offers to search for your local **Prefecture**

---

> **You want to change category**
>
> You can benefit from a **temporary** or multi-year residence permit on the same basis or **other basis than the one under which you were issued your residence permit**.
>
> Conditions to be fulfilled if you wish to benefit from a multi-year residence card:
>   ...
>
> - If it is **for another reason for staying**: you must fulfill the conditions of issue of the temporary residence permit corresponding to the new reason for sojourn;
>
> ...

---

**Sources**:

- [You want to change category](http://accueil-etrangers.gouv.fr/demande-de-titre-de-sejour/vous-etes-ressortissant-e-non-europeen-ne/vous-etes-ressortissant-e-de-pays-tiers-non-algerien-ne/vous-etes-en-france-vous-avez-deja-un-titre-de-sejour/vous-souhaitez-effectuer-son/) (in French)

  - [To obtain a temporary residence card, As a temporary worker](http://accueil-etrangers.gouv.fr/demande-de-titre-de-sejour/vous-etes-ressortissant-e-non-europeen-ne/vous-etes-ressortissant-e-de-pays-tiers-non-algerien-ne/vous-etes-en-france-vous-avez-deja-un-titre-de-sejour/vous-souhaitez-obtenir-son-renouvellement/pour-l-obtention-d-une-carte-de-sejour-temporaire/article/en-tant-que-travailleur-temporaire)

Comment: Hi Mark, I will definitely look into contacting my local Prefecture. It's a bit stressful considering my French isn't great and they don't seem to have services to cater to non-French speakers. Thanks for your response!