# How long can I stay in France after I quit my French Tech job?

Tags: visa, france, residency

I am from a non-EU country and live in France on a French tech visa - *passeport talent* - with a 4 year visa. I've put in my resignation notice and am curious if and for how long my visa will be valid.

Comment: Two related questions and answers: https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/19528/…  and https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/5691/validity-of-schengen-long-stay-scientific-d-visa-after-tendering-resignation-f?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

You can stay until your visa or residence permit is rescinded. It doesn't immediately become invalid because you left your job but since you do not fulfil the conditions anymore, the *préfecture* can move to rescind it.